# How can I make a Java app using the Monkeyrunner API?

Tags: java, android, python, api, monkeyrunner

The Android SDK has an API for sending commands to the phone called Monkeyrunner.  It appears to be a Python API.  Is there anyway I can use it in a Java application?

Answer (score 9):

Well I have been trying to do this, here is what I found (Thanks to google and some help from members on the internet)

Here is a little Java program that uses monkeyrunner to print the name of the device

```
import com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyDevice;
import com.android.monkeyrunner.adb.AdbBackend;

public class Monk {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    Monk monk=new Monk();
    monk.demo();
 }
 public void demo()
 {
    AdbBackend ab = new AdbBackend();
    MonkeyDevice device = ab.waitForConnection();
    //Print Device Name       
    System.out.println(device.getProperty("build.model"));
    device.dispose();
 }
```

}

For the above code too work, I needed to include the following jars monkeyrunner, ddmlib, jython, guavalib, sdklib.

Comment: I'm getting an error with the device.getProperty.

required: org.python.core.PyObject[],java.lang.String[]
found: java.lang.String

Comment: you must have used device.getProperty(PyObject[] pos,String strings) instead of device.getProperty(String string) is my best guess. Please post ur code so that I can have a look at it

Comment: I am sorry, unable to understand why, the code above works for me

Comment: @Harkish am also getting the same error. Can u please post jar version which u are using

Comment: @Harkish I know this question is old, but do you know which jar version you used? If I asked a similar question could you answer for version 26?

Answer (score 6):

Here is an update to @Harkish's answer which works with what I assume to be the current version of MonkeyRunner:

```
import com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbBackend;
import com.android.chimpchat.core.IChimpDevice;

public class MonkeyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // sdk/platform-tools has to be in PATH env variable in order to find adb
        IChimpDevice device = new AdbBackend().waitForConnection();

        // Print Device Name
        System.out.println(device.getProperty("build.model"));

        // Take a snapshot and save to out.png
        device.takeSnapshot().writeToFile("out.png", null);

        device.dispose();
    }
}
```

The library dependencies are:

```
chimpchat.jar, common.jar, ddmlib.jar, guava-13.0.1.jar, sdklib.jar
```

They can all be found in the `sdk/tools/lib` subdirectory of the ADT bundle.

Answer (score 5):

I'm jumping in to provide yet another updated answer.This is what a google dev advised as well.I think it is a more solid implementation and it uses more fail-safe methods.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import com.android.chimpchat.ChimpChat;
import com.android.chimpchat.core.IChimpDevice;


public class MonkeyRunnerTest {

private static final String ADB = "/path-to-your-sdk/sdk/platform-tools/adb";
private static final long TIMEOUT = 5000;

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

       Map<String, String> options = new TreeMap<String, String>();
       options.put("backend", "adb");
       //this is so you don't need to add adb or platform-tools to your system path
       options.put("adbLocation", ADB);
       ChimpChat chimpchat = ChimpChat.getInstance(options);
       //Using this method is advised as to avoid hangs,as this would wait indefinitely
       //Actually waitForConnection() doesn't wait indefinitely but for Integer.MAX_VALUE milliseconds, which still makes up for 596 hours
       IChimpDevice device = chimpchat.waitForConnection(TIMEOUT, ".*");
       chimpchat.shutdown();
    }
  }
```

You can see all the devices properties with:

```
for (String prop: device.getPropertyList()) {
    System.out.println(prop + ": " + device.getProperty(prop));
}
```

For information on the APIs you can look at the docs here: [monkey runner api classes](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html#APIClasses)

Comment: Worked fairly well and quick. On Mac I had challenges to add the jars since I didn't want to copy them elsewhere. I simply created an alias to ~/Library/Android folder and used add external jars to my eclipse project. Trying to figure a better way to use through Maven now. Note - to fetch value of each property MonkeyRunner has to send one event per property to the device, in my case the emulator. But effective

Comment: Works with Android API 28

Comment: combining device.takeSnapshot().writeToFile("out.png", null); with this code throws an device unresponsive exception. I am guessing its a version mismatch of somekind since I am trying it out with bluestack emulator

Comment: @Gautam Will you please tell me from where did you get the jar files and also if can name all the jar files too?

Answer (score 1):

Just to complement the great answer from ValarDohaeris, here it is the current dependencies in maven format:

```
<properties>
    <com.android.tools.version>24.3.1</com.android.tools.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.sociaal</groupId>
        <artifactId>chimpchat</artifactId>
        <version>22.6.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.android.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>sdklib</artifactId>
        <version>${com.android.tools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.android.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>${com.android.tools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.android.tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>sdk-common</artifactId>
        <version>${com.android.tools.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.android.tools.ddms</groupId>
        <artifactId>ddmlib</artifactId>
        <version>${com.android.tools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Currently, the most up-to-date lib appears to be https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jali/jali-adm/1.0.7