# How to do UI automation in android?

Tags: android, automation, monkeyrunner

Is there any guide to do following UI automation like selecting an item, writing text, pressing buttons in Android.
Please list the steps to integrated this UI automation of one of the above thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use it like `python` script.
Example:

```
import sys
import os
import time
import shlex
import subprocess

from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(99, ANDROID_SERIAL_NUMBER)

def Click(device, left, top, duration = 0):
    if duration == 0:
        device.touch(left, top, MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
    else:
        device.touch(left, top, MonkeyDevice.DOWN)
        time.sleep(duration)
        device.touch(left, top, MonkeyDevice.UP)

def Drag_example():
    device.drag((100, 200), (1500, 150), 1, 10) 

def Settings_menu():
    package='com.android.settings'
    activity='.Settings'
    component_name=package + "/" + activity
    device.startActivity(component=component_name)
Settings_menu();
```

For run script use:
`monkeyrunner script_name`

Here is:
`Click` it's function for clicking on screen in x and y position;
`Drag_example` simple example of dragging
`Settings_menu` simple example of running activity

Don't forget to change `ANDROID_SERIAL_NUMBER` to your serial number.
You can get it nu,ber by `adb devices` command.

For more information you can read [google documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html).

For using in Java [read this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686085/how-can-i-make-a-java-app-using-the-monkeyrunner-api)

Comment: For a python script, can you please guide me, where to write the code i.e. the IDE e.g. right now I am using eclipse, now what IDE do I need for this script? After writing a script, how will I run it? :/

Comment: You can write it even in notepad. Run it with command as i provide "monkeyrunner script_name". Monkeyrunner you can find in your "sdk_directory/tools/monkeyrunner" Monkeyrunner it's executable file. Probably you don't need in first 5 lines with import.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) And what should be the extension of the notepad file? To run the script, should I go this directory "Android\android-sdk\tools" ?

Comment: Extansion is no matter, let it be .py as for python. You should run your script something like this way:
"C:\sdk\tools\monkeyrunner.exe script.py".

Comment: Problem in running script file: android-sdk\tools>monkeyrunner test.py.txt
Can't open specified script file
Usage: monkeyrunner [options] SCRIPT_FILE

    -s      MonkeyServer IP Address.
    -p      MonkeyServer TCP Port.
    -v      MonkeyServer Logging level (ALL, FINEST, FINER, FINE, CONFIG, INFO,
WARNING, SEVERE, OFF)

Comment: I try to run it with emulator on windows. It' works perfect. Dont' forget to change  ANDROID_SERIAL_NUMBER on your number.
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection(99, "emulator-5554")
And run line should look like this:
android-sdk-windows\tools>monkeyrunner.bat test.py.txt

Answer (score 5):

Some useful link,

1. [Android: Sample Code To Demonstrate Monkeyrunner](http://crazyrai.blogspot.in/2011/12/monkeyrunner-sample-code-to-demonstrate.html)
2. [Android Guide: monkeyrunner Overview](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/monkeyrunner_concepts.html)
3. [Android Guide: MonkeyDevice](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/MonkeyDevice.html)
4. [Android Guide: MonkeyRunner](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/MonkeyRunner.html)
5. [Monkeyrunner: interacting with the Views](http://dtmilano.blogspot.in/2012/02/monkeyrunner-interacting-with-views.html)  Last link but best...

Answer (score 1):

Automate is an app that can do all jobs you mentioned and many more. You wouldn't need a laptop or ADB connection. Also, no coding is required since programming is in the form of blocks and mostly synchronous.

[Play Store link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample project which I developed to automate an Ebay App where all the above asked UI actions are implemented.

https://github.com/Sivateja0804/EbayAutomationUsingEclipse

go through the link for code repository